# How do I pass a string to an Ajax GET request as a query param without the string getting encoded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am trying to pass a list of subject id's as a query param in an Ajax get-request, so that it only returns data pertaining to the subject id's I passed in. The API is set up to receive a `subjectId` param as a single number, or string of numbers separated by commas. I have made sure that what I am sending is exactly that -- `"13,14,15"` -- but when I make the request, the get URL encodes the string so that it looks like this: `13%2C14%2C15%2C`.

The URL I *want* to generate is (I'm just using placeholders for the domain name and session token)  `https://get-url.com/get-filter-counts?sessionToken=abcdefg&subjectId=13,14,15`. When I test this out in the browser, it works.

The URL I'm *actually* generating is `https://get-url.com/get-filter-counts?sessionToken=abcdefg&subjectId=13%2C14%2C15%2C`

I've tried researching this issue but I'm not even sure what it is that's happening there. I've looked at a ton of examples of passing strings as query params in an Ajax request, and as far as I can tell I'm doing it correctly. I've hard-coded a string into the params below just to demonstrate:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: getURL,
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        sessionToken: sessionToken,
        subjectId: "13,14,15"
      },

      //process the returned result of the Ajax call
      success: (ajaxResult) => {
        console.log("subject id list:", subjectId);
        console.log("Ajax result:", ajaxResult);
      },
```

In the success method, the console returns the correct subjectId list as well as the data pertaining to those subject id's. But I am unable to get the results in the browser because of this URL issue.

How can I remove the encoding (if that's what's happening?) from the string in the url? Thanks.

Comment: If having URL encoded data in a URL breaks whatever is parsing the URL then **the problem is with the server failing to handle a properly encoded URL**, not with the client for encoding it. Fix the server. Don't worry about the client.

Comment: Why not pass an array in both cases and handle it accordingly on the server?

Comment: Ok thanks -- I am just building out the frontend and working with the API as the backend engineers set it up. Originally I could only pass one subject ID at a time and had to make the network request once for every subject I needed data on, which was extremely slow, so I asked if I could send a list of subject ID's. I assumed they'd set it up to receive an array of ID's, but then they said I had to send them as a string. I can circle back with them if the encoding issue needs to be handled on their end, but since I wasn't sure what was going on, I wanted to get more info first.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with using commas in-between numbers. The string you are sending from the frontend is getting encoded and hence the URL you see. If you try `encodeURIComponent(13,14,15)` you'll see the same response.
The solution would be using something other than commas and handling that on the backend or simply sending an array.

Comment: Ok thanks, good to know. The backend engineers want to use a string with commas, so I ended up just writing `subjectId = subjectIdString.slice(0, -1)` in order to remove the trailing comma at the end. I'm looping through the subjects and adding each id to the string `subjectIdString += `${subject.subject_id},`, so no way to avoid creating the trailing comma and then removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was sending the string of numbers with a trailing comma at the end (I didn't think that would be an issue), and it turns out that's why the server wasn't properly handling the encoded URL. Just sharing in case this is useful for anyone else who looks at this question.

The comment from @Quentin was essentially correct, except the issue was in fact a frontend typo.